# Formward / rewind animation frame by frame on legacy system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to control and animation using legacy system, must be able to forward / backward while specific keys are pressed.

Currentyl tried to control current frame on Start Method:

```
    ani.GetComponent<Animation>()["myAnim"].time = .3f;
    ani.speed=0;
```

However it doesn't seem to do anything (nor it prints error / warnings).

If I do check "Play automatically" in animation component, it begins animation on given time (or so it seems), but doesn't pause.

An idea on how to properly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AnimationClip.SampleAnimation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html)

E.g. something like

```c#
[SerializeField] private AnimationClip _clip;

[SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;

private float sampleTime;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        sampleTime = Mathf.Min(_clip.Length, sampleTime + Time.deltaTime * speed);
        _clip.SampleAnimation(gameObject, sampleTime);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        sampleTime = Mathf.Max(0, sampleTime - Time.deltaTime * speed);
        _clip.SampleAnimation(gameObject, sampleTime);
    }
}
```